# Allow pasting a question's URL when closing a duplicate question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions

When I close a question because of duplicate, I usually paste the URL into the textbox. Sometimes it works, sometimes not (it's search, after all).

So, this feature is to detect when I'm pasting a URL of a question and extract the ID from it.

Comment: Yes! That drives me crazy.

Answer (score 8):

This already works, I do it all the time.

Comment: If you right click the URL you want to paste into it (if one is already listed in the box) and you paste that URL with your mouse only, then you have to hit something on the keyboard to make it register. I believe that is what he's talking about.

Comment: It even works in **Opera**. And with just the keyboard too.

Comment: @random "Just the Keyboard" has always been fine. It's a problem when you try to use "Just the Mouse."

Comment: Just the mouse occasionally requires double-clicking the input field to fire up the lookup.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I've fixed this in the next build; mouse pasting will also trigger the lookup.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen that sometimes I need to press the "down" button on my keyboard after pasting for the question to be searched, but that is about all the problems I've had with that.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work? This is how I've always closed questions. Can you come up with a case where pasting the URL doesn't work?

Comment: umm.. right-click and select "paste" ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Greasemonkey script so you don't even have to extract the ID:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21826/greasemonkey-easier-vote-to-close-for-duplicates